# javascript serialize map object

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dictionary

Crazy Idea!
I will like to share all shapes (circle, polygons, lines) I drawn on a map.

It is possible to save a map object, maybe serialize this object and then reloaded.

```
   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
            mapOptions);
```

This will be a kind of fiddle for maps shapes

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should take a look to the GeoJson :
https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/data/importing_data
It offers a way to serialize your shapes in an universal JSON object